# Passing URL to Views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my controller code:

```
$view = View::make('homepage');
$loglink = URL::route('account.login');
$view->loglink = $loglink;
return $view;
```

Here is how I recv it in view:

```
<a href="{{ $loglink }}" class="red">
```

I get an **error** saying:

```
Undefined variable: loglink (View:
C:\BottleBookings\server\app\views\partials\header.blade.php)
```

Any problem with the way I am sending or recving it?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how view creation works. Just `return` your view and pass the variables you want to use with the `with()` function in the same command. Create your view like this:

```
$loglink = URL::route('account.login');
return View::make('homepage')->with('loglink', $loglink);
```

Or even shorter:

```
return View::make('homepage')->with('loglink', URL::route('account.login'));
```

Also, you don't really have to pass the link URLs, it's perfectly fine to generate them where they are needed in the view:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('account.login') }}" class="red">
```

Comment: I still get the same error. I am calling the view page 'homepage'. This view page extends another view page called 'main'. This 'main' includes a 'header' view page. This 'header' view page contains the HTML code which recvs the loglink variable. Is it because I am calling the homepage view where as the HTML line I posted is present in the file called header?

Comment: In the view page, I cannot use a static link(<a href="{{ URL::route('account.login') }}" class="red">). It changes based on conditions. The URL account.login may change if conditions are different which I check in the controller.

Comment: @user3639379 Did you created a route that is called `account.login`? What happens if you give `$loglink` some other value like `$loglink = 'test'`?

Comment: yes I do have such a route. It works perfect if my view has the static line URL::route('account.login'). But doesnt work if i pass the same through my controller.

Comment: I just found another way to do it.

In my view page I added this line:
    if($logstatus = 'Login')
    <li><a href="{{ URL::route('account.login') }}" class="red">{{ $logstatus }}</a></li> 
    else
    <li><a href="{{ URL::route('account.logout') }}" class="red">{{ $logstatus }}</a></li>
    endif

I pass the variable through logstatus. Checking the condition inside my view page than in my controller. However, it would be useful someone can help me check the conditions in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

why you complicate. just put the datas in array and pass it to view.

**Controller**

```
$data['loglink'] = URL::route('account.login');
return View::make('homepage',$data);
```

p.s. your loglink variable will be available to only `homepage` view. **NOT** on header page.

if you want to pass the loglink to header, then you have to pass it as `View::composer` or `View::share` or where you are including the file. any one of the three will do.